# Как оптимизировать конкатенацию строк?

Tags: c++, строки, оптимизация, производительность

Программа конкатенирует n строк. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее можно оптимизировать?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


char* concat(char* pref, char* suff)
{
    for (; *pref; ++pref);
    while (*pref++ = *suff++);
    return pref;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char** str = new char* [n];
    str[0] = new char[1000000];
    cin >> str[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        str[i] = new char[100];
        cin >> str[i];
    }
    char* c = str[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) c = concat(str[0], str[i]);
    for (int i = 0; str[0][i] && cout << str[0][i]; i++);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) delete[] str[i];
}
```

Comment: 1) нет языка в метках. 2) нет "пожалуйста" в вопросе.

Comment: @Сергей по п.2 - в вопросе должно быть не "пожалуйста", а четкое описание проблемы )

Comment: @Сергей, спасибо за замечания.

Comment: @Kromster, оно там +/- было. Да и автор понял всё верно. Теперь шанс, что знатоки "плюсов" ответят, повысился:-)

Comment: Вообще-то вот это — `cin >> str[i];` — в современном С++ некомпилируемо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если считать, что `cin >> str[i]` работает, что, вообще-то, уже нестандарт, то можно конкатенировать, просто читая по указателю, указывающему на конец строки. Как я понял, никакие строковые функции не разрешены.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char * str = new char[1000000], * s = str;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> s;
        while(*++s);
    }
    cout << str;
    delete[] str;
}
```

[Годится](https://ideone.com/LsxxmX)?

В любом случае храните окончание предыдущей строки и продолжайте писать дальше, без поиска окончания предыдущей строки заново.